# Artifactory token created on LDAP integrated AD User still works with associated AD account is locked or disabled

Tags: api, active-directory, ldap, token, artifactory

Artifactory token created on LDAP integrated AD User still works with associated AD account is locked or disabled.

I expect api access via token to fail if underlying AD account is locked or disabled.

Is this a known bug or is there a configuration issue to address this?  Thanks!

Artifactory: 7.35.2

Comment: We faced the same issue on `Artifactory version : 7.71.5 (Self-Hosted)`. Even when LDAP user was disable API keys was still working.